# SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL within a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

When I want to add the line

> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

right after BEGIN clause of my function definition script in SQL SERVER 2008,
it says:

```
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL' within a function
```

How can I achive this functionality within a function definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  [UDFs do not support set operations.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-user-defined-functions-udf-limitations/)

<del>A function is always executing within the context of a transaction (implicitly or explicitly), and you can't change the isolation level of a transaction once it has begun.</del>

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx "With one exception, you can switch from one isolation level to another at any time during a transaction. The exception occurs when changing from any isolation level to SNAPSHOT isolation. Doing this causes the transaction to fail and roll back. However, you can change a transaction started in SNAPSHOT isolation to any other isolation level." - You are correct- I missed that.  I'll delete the answer if the OP unmarks it as accepted

Comment: I've retracted my DV because you're stuck with it now it's accepted. Maybe just edit it so it's correct.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

You need to set this at the start of the batch that calls the function.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this to get around not being able to set transaction isolation?

```
Select * from dbo.MyTable with (nolock)
```